# Adding missing punctuations before a closing HTML tag

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace, regex-group

My string is an HTML document. I want to add a dot before HTML closing tags when there is not punctuation right before. Punctuation is `.,?!:` and I want to use `preg_replace` for that.

```
<p>Today, not only we have so many breeds that are trained this and that.</p>

<h4><strong>We must add a dot after the closing strong</strong></h4>

<p>Hunting with your dog is a blah blah with each other.</p>

<h2>No need to change this one!</h2>

<p>Hunting with your dog is a blah blah with each other.</p>
```

My function:

```
$source = 'the above html';
$source = addMissingPunctuation( $source );

echo $source;

function addMissingPunctuation( $input ) {

    $tags = [ 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6' ];

    foreach ($tags as $tag) {

        $input = preg_replace(
            "/[^,.;!?](<\/".$tag.">)/mi",
            ".${0}",
            $input
        );

    }

    return $input;
}
```

I tried `.${0}`,`.$0`, `.${1}`,`.$1`, `.\\0`,`.\\1` but nothing works. At best, it swallows the match but doesn't replace it with anything. The matching part of my pattern seems to work on regex101 and other sites.

Desired result is:

```
<p>Today, not only we have so many breeds that are trained this and that.</p>

<h4><strong>We must add a dot after the closing strong</strong>.</h4>

<p>Hunting with your dog is a blah blah with each other.</p>

<h2>No need to change this one!</h2>

<p>Hunting with your dog is a blah blah with each other.</p>
```

Comment: it work chris, will dissect it to understand why... thanks a lot, been scratching my heads for a while... if you put it as answer i can mark it as Solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to iterate over the `$tags` like that, I'd either do an `implode` with `|`, or in this case just right a rule for all possible elements.

```
$source = '<p>Today, not only we have so many breeds that are trained this and that.</p>

<h4><strong>We must add a dot after the closing strong</strong></h4>

<p>Hunting with your dog is a blah blah with each other.</p>

<h2>No need to change this one!</h2>

<p>Hunting with your dog is a blah blah with each other.</p>';
$source = addMissingPunctuation( $source );
echo $source;
function addMissingPunctuation( $input ) {
    return preg_replace("/[^,.;!?]\K<\/h[1-6]>/mi", ".$0", $input);
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/6dNV7

You also need to ignore what ever character was before the element, the `\K` does that. The `${}` is for a PHP variable the `$0` is the capture group, might be clearer if you write it with `\0` in the future.

Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/xUvvuf/1/

(Example using the `\0`. https://3v4l.org/jGZal)

Another approach you could take is skipping all the elements with the punctuation, this cuts the steps down a bit.

https://regex101.com/r/xUvvuf/2/

```
[,.;!?]<\/h[1-6]>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|<\/h[1-6]>
```

You also could change the [delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php); this is more personal preference though. If you don't mind escaping the `/`s you can keep doing that, if not just swap the leading and closing `/` with a `~`.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/xUvvuf/3/

```
preg_replace("~[^,.;!?]\K</h[1-6]>~mi"
```

Comment: This is a good one chris.  The only point that I feel is missing is the advice to change the pattern delimiter to `~` or something so that the forward slashes inside the pattern don't need to be escaped.  Otherwise, you choked me out of this page -- there is nothing valuable that I can post!

Comment: I would like to hear your thoughts on a question I have.  Please join me here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159717/feedback-about-a-question-deleted